# Magento 2.4.0 upgrade to 2.4.3 error

Tags: php, composer, magento-upgrade, magento2.4.0

I am getting error while upgrading Magento 2.4.0 CE to 2.4.3 while executing `setup:upgrade` command.

Cannot instantiate interface `Magento\MediaContentSynchronizationApi\Model\GetEntitiesInterface#0 /chroot/home/a7aa3bd3/stage.mcfeelys.com/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\MediaCo...')`

I have used below procedure

1. `composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3 --no-update`
2. `composer update`

After that, I have executed `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and then I got above error.

I have tried all things like removing generated folder,cleared cache etc.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried flushing redis?

Comment: @PerryHolden this is staging site and redis is not enabled

Answer (score 0):

The error message you provided suggests that there is an issue with the GetEntitiesInterface in the Magento\MediaContentSynchronizationApi module.

To resolve this issue, you can try the following steps:

1. Check if the Magento\MediaContentSynchronizationApi module is installed and enabled in your Magento instance.
2. Check if all the dependencies of this module are met.
3. Run the composer update command to ensure that all dependencies are up to date.
4. Check if there are any conflicts or issues with other modules that may be causing this error.
5. If the issue persists, you can try disabling the Magento\MediaContentSynchronizationApi module temporarily to see if the error disappears. If it does, you can try re-installing the module or contacting the developer for assistance.